# How do you send a body with an erroring http response in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm converting an ASP.NET Web API project to ASP.NET Core WEB API. Before, we would return erroring responses like so:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(ErrorResponses.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Too many linked devices", new { status = (int)SignInStatus.TooManyLinkedDevices }));
```

Notice how we've set the http status code, an error message, and a response body. In Core, I can do this:

```
return Conflict("Too many linked devices");
```

However, I'm not seeing a way to also set the response body. What is the proper technique to achieve this?

Comment: Please read the link thoroughly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @TanvirArjel I see nothing in there that answers my question...

Comment: Okay! give me time please! Hope by this time someone help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what each param in the "old" code is corresponding to exactly, but there's only one response body, so logically, returning both a "Too many linked devices" string and an object is not possible. Either the string or the object was not actually being returned in the response body.

That said, your response body with `Conflict` is the param you're passing to it currently. That can either be an object (string is an object) or a `ModelStateDictionary` (i.e. `ModelState`). You probably need to do something like the following:

```
return Conflict(new {
    message = "Too many linked devices",
    status = (int)SignInStatus.TooManyLinkedDevices
})
```